# Need to Handle Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

[image]I need to somehow handle a null exception in this part of the code `txtHandle.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`
my whole code is:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        string fNameTemp = txtUsername.Text;
        string sqlquery = ("SELECT Username FROM Userstbl 
                             WHERE (Username =  '" + fNameTemp + "')");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
        txtHandle.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Is there any special reason not using try-catch?

Comment: just check if its null before doing that line? What is the *exact* problem you are having?

Comment: well i did try to use Try Catch but got the same error though, dont know if i did it wrong.. i thought maybe there is another way beside try catch

Comment: Try catch shouldn't be your *first* response to seeing an exception, especially for an exception like `NullReferenceException`. You have to think first - is that an exceptional case or not? Do I want to handle it or let someone else? In your case, it's obvious that it's perfectly valid for the query to return a `null` value ("user not found"), and you should handle that case appropriately. You might want to read up a bit on proper exception / error handling, it's one of the things that can bite you real bad.

Comment: i edited the post sorry i wasnt being clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely `ExecuteScalar` will return `string` in this case (or `null`), so there is no need for calling `ToString()`, just cast it:

```
txtHandle.Text = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

Or, if you need to do something other than set the text to `null` in the `null` case:

```
var result = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;

if (result != null)
{
    txtHandle.Text = result;
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In c# 6.0 you would also be able to use the new `?.` operator `txtHandle.Text = command.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning your query result to the TextBox you can use a string. Strings are of reference type and so can be null.

You can go like this:

```
string result = command.Executescalar() as string;
if (result != null) {
     txtHandle.Text = result 
}
```

Or you can use the `String.IsNullorEmpty` method